# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'play') and Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pause')

Tags: javascript

In the application, there are a video background and one button for start and stop (the button image should change from play to stop) simultaneously the video and the music,
but when I click the button, the sound starts but not the video, and then if I click it another time it stops.
The video doesn't start and the img of the button doesn't change.

This is the code.

```js
const app = () => {
  const song = document.querySelector(".song");
  const play = document.querySelector(".play");
  const outline = document.querySelector(".moving-outline circle");
  const video = document.querySelector(".vid-container button");

  //sounds
  const sounds = document.querySelectorAll(".sound-picker button");

  //time display
  const timeDisplay = document.querySelector(".time-display");

  // get length of the outline
  const outlineLength = outline.getTotalLength();

  //duration
  let fakeDuration = 600;

  outline.style.strokeDasharray = outlineLength;
  outline.style.strokeDashoffset = outlineLength;

  //play sound
  play.addEventListener("click", () => {
    checkPlaying(song);
  });

  // func specific to stop and play the sounds

  const checkPlaying = (song) => {
    if (song.paused) {
      song.play();
      video.play();
      play.src = "./svg/pause.svg";
    } else {
      song.pause();
      video.pause();
      play.src = "./svg/play.svg";
    }
  };
};

app();
```

Thanks for reading !!

Comment: Please include your html; either `song` or `video` is not defined when you attempt to call `play()` or `pause()`.

Comment: You should probably re-query for song or video when checking state, instead of using initial value (which is null)